# Supporting TLS 1.2 in Zumero

Tags: c#, zumero

We are using Zumero for our product to replicate data from SQL Server to the SQLite on the Android and iOS devices.

We recently have some changes in our application server to support only TLS 1.2 as TLS 1.1 is no more supported due to security vulnerability.

We are seeing that the communication from the Zumero application server to SQL Server is failing due to this TLS 1.1 to TLS 1.2 change. We are getting encryption error every time we are trying to sync the replication.

Can you please let us know if Zumero supports TLS 1.2 and how to configure this change in the existing Zumero application server from TLS 1.1 to TLS 1.2 ?

This issue was reported from our customer on their production server, we are using SQL Server 2019.

Comment: Who makes Zumero, and can you get in touch with them? This sounds like a technical support issue.

Comment: It could be the certificate that is being used.  The encryption mode may not be supported.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 0):

For reference, the best way to get quick support from Zumero is to email support@zumero.com (which Sumanta did).

For this particular issue, the problem is that the version 11 of the SQL Native ODBC client that is normally shipped with the Zumero server does not support TLS 1.2. The solution is to install the latest ODBC driver version 11 from Microsoft. The driver should be installed on the IIS machine that runs the Zumero server.

MS has a KB article about that at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3135244-tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server-e4472ef8-90a9-13c1-e4d8-44aad198cdbe

Under Client component downloads, the one you need is SQL Server Native Client 11.0 for SQL Server 2012/2014 (x86/x64). Specifically, the x64 version.